# Git: Squashing consecutive commits that are not the most recent commits, and do not start at the root

Tags: git, version-control, jgit, squash

I have reviewed several related questions about [squashing the most recent commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189560/squash-my-last-x-commits-together-using-git/5201642#5201642) and [squashing a commit at the root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/598672/squash-the-first-two-commits-in-git/598788#598788), but neither will help me squash non-recent commits that are not at the root.

Here is my starting scenario:

```
D---E---F---G---H---I---J master
```

and my desired result:

```
D---E---Z---I---J master
```

where `Z` is the squash of `F---G---H`, and `F---G---H`, `D---E`, and `I---J` can be an arbitrarily long sequence of non-branching commits.

**First approach:**

```
[lucas]/home/blah/$ git rebase -i D
rebase in progress; onto D
You are currently editing a commit while rebasing branch 'master' on 'D'.

No changes
You asked to amend the most recent commit, but doing so would make
it empty. You can repeat your command with --allow-empty, or you can
remove the commit entirely with "git reset HEAD^".

Could not apply F... "Comments from commit F"

[1]+  Done                    gitk
[lucas]/home/blah/$
```

where I select commits `F---G---H` to be `squash`, while leaving the oldest commit - the first line in the rebase interactive - as `pick`. Why doesn't this work?

Update: at the end of the command, a rebase is in progress on `D` with `E` being the HEAD commit. To be sure, there was no rebase in progress at the start and calling `git rebase --abort` while running again has the same result. When I do this at root, or HEAD, according to the links above, everything works fine.

**Second approach:**

I made another attempt [via merging a new branch (last post on the forum)][http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/Non-interactive-squash-a-range-td5251049.html) which uses `git checkout -b <clean-branch> <start-id> and`git merge --squash `, but I get the following:

```
[lucas-ThinkPad-W520]/home/.../.Solstice_WS/7K_FGHF$ git checkout -b clean-branch D
Switched to branch 'clean-branch'
[lucas-ThinkPad-W520]/home/.../.Solstice_WS/7K_FGHF$ git merge --squash I
Updating D..I
Fast-forward
Squash commit -- not updating HEAD
 .../GraphUtilities/impl/DAG.java              | 7 ++-----
 1 file changed, 2 insertions(+), 5 deletions(-)
[lucas]/home/blah/$ git checkout master
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
        asdf/GraphUtilities//DAG.java
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
Aborting
```

which seems to have this result:

```
  -------------------  <clean-branch> with non-committed changes
 / 
D---E---F---G---H---I---J <master>
```

I am a bit stumped, so how can I squash these commits?

Ultimately, I plan to implement this in `JGit`, so a `JGit` implementation would be acceptable as well.

**NOTE**

There may be a [duplicate here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16763569/how-to-squash-consecutive-commit-objects-into-one), but it has no answers and I think the question is a bit unclear.

**UPDATE**

This is in response to @ryenus's answer below:

The cherry-pick fails on the commit `I2`, where `I2` is in `I---I2---J`. When it fails, the state of my `work` branch has `D---E---Z`, as intended up until the cherry-pick, and it is followed by uncommitted changes. Calling `git cherry-pick --abort` clears these uncommitted changes, and I verified that commit `Z` is correct, which is the squash of `F---G---H`. After committing `Z`, then cherry-picking, why does the cherry-pick fail at `F`?

It seems as though `git cherry-pick I...J` is trying to cherry-pick `I2`, which creates the merge conflict and fails. Any suggestions?

Here is my output:

```
[lucas]/home$ git checkout -b work H
Switched to a new branch 'work'
[lucas]/home$ git reset E             
Unstaged changes after reset:
M       adf/GraphUtilities//graph/impl/DAG.java
[lucas]/home$ git commit -am "squashed commit here!"
[work Z] squashed commit here!
 1 file changed, 2 insertions(+), 5 deletions(-)
[lucas]/home$ git cherry-pick I...J
error: could not apply I2... <Comments from commit I2>
hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths
hint: with 'git add <paths>' or 'git rm <paths>'
hint: and commit the result with 'git commit'
[lucas]/home/$ git status
On branch work
You are currently cherry-picking commit I2.
  (fix conflicts and run "git cherry-pick --continue")
  (use "git cherry-pick --abort" to cancel the cherry-pick operation)

Unmerged paths:
  (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)

        both modified:      3b6863741967406c1888701eb139178187d429487b99787096441d67bed56/Gra
phUtilities/src/edu/washington/cs/utils/graph/impl/DAG.java

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
[lucas]/home$
```

Comment: Your first approach seems to be the right start, but it looks like git thinks you're in the middle of a rebase. Counterintuitively, rebases and merges are stateful, and git can cede control back to you before a merge/rebase is finished. Try `git rebase --abort` and then do that command again.

Comment: It looks more like the output of `git status` if he specified "edit" for one of the commits.  Git will say `I wonder if you are in the middle of another rebase` if you type `git rebase` while a rebase is in progress.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, if `F---G---H` are squashed, then `I---J` would be `I'---J'`.

Given that, I'd create a branch first then use vanilla `git reset` then `git cherry-pick`:

```
# D---E---F---G---H---I---J master
```

1. `git checkout -b work H`

   create branch `work` at `H`
2. `git reset E`

   now `work` is at `E`
3. `git commit -am "F-G-H squeezed as Z"`

   commit the changes done by `F---G---H` as `Z`
4. `git cherry-pick I^..J`

   take over `I---J`

Now the `work` branch is in the shape you want, just reset `master` to it:

```
# D---E---Z---I`---J` work

git checkout master
git reset work
git branch -d work
```

Note: the commit range has been corrected to `I^..J`, to represent the commit series `I---J` (from `I` to `J`, inclusive).

Comment: Interesting approach, but the cherry-pick is failing. It appears to be trying to cherry-pick `F` onto `work` after `Z` has been committed. Details are updated in my answer above.

Comment: @Lucas, please try `git cherry-pick I^..J`, if it works I'll update the answer.

Comment: After reviewing Git's [revision selection](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection), this makes sense now. Thank you! Also, the cherry-pick was not failing at `F` but at `I2` where `I2` is in `I---I2---J` (I updated my post accordingly)

Comment: Also, would this solution be suitable if `I---J` was a very long sequence of non-branching commits? Say, around 1000 commits?

Comment: @Lucas, yes, it should just works, because here `H` and `Z` have the same content, thus all following commits should apply perfectly.

Comment: As you showed above, this also rewrites the commits `I---J` to `I'---J'`. Is it possible to preserve the original commits as well? Can we replace `F--G--H` on the `master` branch with `Z`? Perhaps there is a way to delete `F--G--H` on `master` then cherry-pick `Z` into the same spot? I can make this a separate question, but let me know what you think.

Comment: @Lucas, no, commit hash is a result of the commit itself and its parent commit. With a different parent commit, the new commit would not have the same commit hash. But except the commit hash, `I'---J'` are just the same as `I---J`.